# How can I adapt the official Vue filter example to use Vuetify's `v-text-field`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

What I'm trying to do is apply the following Vue example from the docs to use a v-text-field component: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Two-Way-Filters-replaced

When using a simple input field, it's working fine, but when using a v-text-field, it leads to what is being shown in the field does not match the value itself (as can be seen with Vue Devtools).

I created a CodePen demonstrating my problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpvaWQ. I'm replacing the basic `input` field:

```
<input
    ref="input"
    v-bind:value="value"
    v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
    v-on:focus="selectAll"
    v-on:blur="formatValue"
>
```

with Vuetify's `v-text-field`:

```
<v-text-field
    ref="input"
    v-bind:value="value"
    v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
    v-on:focus="selectAll"
    v-on:blur="formatValue"
><v-text-field>
```

The first field is the example from the Vue docs, the second field is the same one but then with a v-text-field component instead of an input field.
Typing in the first field works as expected (like in the Vue docs), but typing in the second field doesn't format the number in the same way as the first field does.

To reproduce the problem: type in `12.3456` in the first field and then in the second field. The value is correctly cut off in the first field, but is not cut off in the second field.

Anyone has an idea about how to fix this?

Comment: Your codepen throws error when typing `"[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for 'input': 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'`

Comment: @barbsan Ok, fixed that warning in the updated CodePen

Comment: @lowerends https://www.dropbox.com/s/5tqfbz3cad7vedq/2018-07-26_11-06-27.mp4?dl=0 both fields act same, what u mean? ALso there no closed v-text-field and u shouldnt mutatre props

Comment: Now you get `"[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: 'value'` before typing anything

Comment: @barbsan That is one of the issues that I'm trying to solve actually for this particular use case.

Comment: @Aldarund Thanks. I've updated the question with an example of how the problem manifests itself.

Comment: It's not one of issues, it's the main one - first time you enter third digit after decimal point it gets erased and again that warn is thrown and then you can type anything, including letters (if you type letter first, then you can also type anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is in `this.$refs.input.value` because `v-text-field` is component and this field is not related to internal `<input>` tag value.

The workaround is to use some internal field, watch main value prop and change internal field in `nextTick` to correct value - I forked codepen, see this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBvZEq

Also as another solution you can access "native" input value of `v-text-field` like this

```
this.$refs.input.$el.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
```

but I think it will bring some new issues and looks as "dirty" way.

Comment: Thanks, this really is a very useful solution. One thing though: when typing an alpha character, is there a way to avoid seeing the glitch of that character? In the current solution, disallowed characters are displayed very briefly before they disappear.

Comment: @lowerends  it is due to `$nextTick` executes a bit later, unfortunately it can be avoided only with directly changing "native" input value in the same "time tick"(as in your question codepen).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use because you are mutating props.

`this.$refs.input.value = currencyValidator.format(this.value)`

instead you should use $emit input:

`this.$emit('input', currencyValidator.format(this.value))`

Don't forget to emit it as number.